# Does AES-128-GCM authenticate the IV on Node V6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, encryption, cryptography

Given this code:

```
const bufIV = Buffer.alloc(16);
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(CIPHER, mykey, crypto.randomFillSync(bufIV));
let encrypted = cipher.update(doc, 'utf8', ENCODING);
encrypted += cipher.final(ENCODING);
```

Will the IV also be authenticated? The end of [this article](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059609995/crypto-noobs-1-initialization-vectors) seems to indicate that it needs to be, but I don't really understand how this works.

> Using a good IV doesn’t automatically mean your crypto is secure. You have to authenticate your ciphertexts, too. When you do, don’t forget to authenticate the IV.

Comment: The article you're referring to is not about GCM mode, so it doesn't fully apply. The IV only needs to unique for every encryption with the same key. The authentication they are referring to is a MAC in addition to CTR/CBC mode.

Comment: So I don't need to worry about it for a one time key?

Comment: Note that the IV should be 12 bytes; not 16. Differently sized IV's are supported by the GCM algorithm, but they could be less secure and they are discouraged by NIST (so they might not be supported on all platforms).

Comment: @Maarten, 128/8=16? Isn't it supposed to be the size of a block?

Comment: Most of the time, yes. But the *requirements for the IV depend on the mode of operation*, and for GCM it is certainly a 12 bytes nonce (by default anyway). Read the GCM specification of NIST if you're not sure! CBC requires a 16 bytes nonce that cannot be predicted by an adversary.

Comment: Just came across the specs for this. The 12 byte nonce is required for TLS, but only recommended in the AES-GCM spec as being the most efficient. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5084 and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5288

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AES-GCM will automatically verify the IV, verification of the IV is included within the calculation of the authentication tag.

Now for the bad news: as you need to explicitly set the received authentication tag in NodeJS using the [`setAuthTag`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_decipher_setauthtag_buffer) *nothing* will be verified in the code you've shown us.

Comment: Good catch about setAuthTag. I promptly ran into this problem next :)